# How can I get group details by @link using Telebot library

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I want to create a bot that posts messages on channels / groups,
the user sends the group address for example: @group_name, and I need to get the ID, title
I work with telebot library

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['addgroup'])
def add_group(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Send group link without @')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, add)

def add(message):
    url = "telegram.me/" + message.text
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("##HERE I NEED GROUP NAME##", url=url))
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Add this group?", reply_markup=keyboard)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, check_group)
    ....
```

How can I get this information?

Answer (score 1):

Let's read telegram docs...

#### [getChat](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchat)

Use this method to get up to date information about the chat (current name of the user for one-on-one conversations, current username of a user, group or channel, etc.).
Returns a [Chat](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chat) object on success.

Parameters:
`chat_id` - unique identifier for the target chat or username of the target supergroup or channel (in the format @channelusername).

So,

```py
chat = bot.get_chat('@username')
```

P.S.: `register_next_step_handler` is antipattern, use `aiogram`'s FSM instead.